# I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS . I am trying to compile simple Kernel Module Program

Tags: kernel, compiling

but when I run Makefile by "make" command this error terminates the compilation

Whats the solution to this issue:

Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler

Comment: The compiler that the `Makefile` is using (which one is that?) does not support the `-fstack-protector` switch, which is also specified in the `Makefile`. Which "Kernel Module Program" are you trying to compile? Were you sup;posed to run `./configure` first?

Comment: Compiler is gcc 4.8 version. And I'm trying to compile simple /simplest kernel module program which just prints some text in the sys log.

Comment: I'm using `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)`. `man gcc` tells me `

Comment: I'm using `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)`. `gcc -v --help` tells me `  -fstack-protector           Use propolice as a stack protection method`. Searching for `propolice` leads me to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProPolice#GNU_Compiler_Collection_.28GCC.29`., which you should read. Or, edit the `Makefile` and delete `-fstack-protector`.  Double comment due to timeout while I researched.

Comment: Thanx for the info. i read the page....But how to delete -fstack-protector,if its the solution as you said above?